# getPreferences raising the NullPointerException

Tags: java, android

I am trying to implement SharedPreferences in my code, which stores image file names.

This is the code I am using to implement the SharedPreferences -

```
private void setpath(String path2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
System.out.println("sharedpreferences "+path2);
try{
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,0); //I am getting NullPointerException here.
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString("name",path2);
Log.v("path in setpath of MyFileOberver : ",path2);
editor.commit();
Intent i=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ArrAdapter.class);
i.putExtra("path", path);
    startActivity(i);       
}
catch(Exception e)
{
    Log.v("Exception in SharedPreferences : ",e.toString());
}
}
```

ArrAdapter.java :

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.fileeventlist);
info = new adapter(this);
listView = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
setContentView(R.layout.fileeventlist);
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences (PREFS_NAME,0);
    String newpath = "newpath";
    this.path = settings.getString("name",newpath);
    Log.v("New path in FileEvent : ",newpath);


    }
```

The logcat shows the following message -

```
09-27 11:07:14.141: A/FileObserver(14481): Unhandled exception in FileObserver com.example.sample_fileobserver.MyFileObserver@b1178718
09-27 11:07:14.141: A/FileObserver(14481): java.lang.NullPointerException
09-27 11:07:14.141: A/FileObserver(14481):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getSharedPreferences(ContextWrapper.java:167)
09-27 11:07:14.141: A/FileObserver(14481):  at com.example.sample_fileobserver.FileEvent.setpath(FileEvent.java:135)
```

I am unable to understand, where my code is going wrong.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: there must be line number in the logcat

Comment: In your logcat, find any message including `ArrAdapter.java:XX` XX being the faulty line's number.

Comment: Thanks for your comments Carp and @DjHacktorReborn, I have updated the logcat in the question. Please see it.

Comment: The only thing I see on that line that could be null is `PREFS_NAME`. Is it?

Comment: No @Geobits, it is not null. I have declared it as `public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPreferencesFile";`

Comment: where are you using `setpath` are you calling it in `onCreate` or any other function .

Comment: I am calling `setpath()` from another function(not from `onCreate()`), which is called by another class.

Comment: `ContextWrapper.java:167` indicates that your `Context` may be null somehow.

Comment: how can I check it? @Geobits

Comment: It's a lifecycle problem, most likely. Trace the program flow for us and edit it into the question.

Comment: How can I trace it @Geobits ? I can't understand what you are asking me. Sorry if the question is too straight forward.

Comment: Start from your main activity's `onCreate()` method. Look at your code and figure out where it goes from there, all the way to `setPath()`. Write down everything you do in between.

Answer (score 1):

Is PREFS_NAME correctly initialized?